# What's wrong with fillna in Pandas running twice?

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I'm new to Pandas and Numpy. I was trying to solve the [Kaggle | Titanic Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic). Now I have to fix the two columns, "Age" and "Embarked" because they contains NAN.

Now I tried the `fillna` without any success, soon to discover that I was missing the `inplace = True`.

Now I attached them. But the first imputation was successful but the second one was not. I tried searching in SO and google, but did not find anything useful. Please help me.

Here's the code that I was trying.

```
# imputing "Age" with mean
titanic_df["Age"].fillna(titanic_df["Age"].mean(), inplace = True)
    
# imputing "Embarked" with mode
titanic_df["Embarked"].fillna(titanic_df["Embarked"].mode(), inplace = True)

print titanic_df["Age"][titanic_df["Age"].isnull()].size
print titanic_df["Embarked"][titanic_df["Embarked"].isnull()].size
```

and I got the output as

```
0
2
```

However I managed to get what I want without using `inplace=True`

```
titanic_df["Age"] =titanic_df["Age"].fillna(titanic_df["Age"].mean())
titanic_df["Embarked"] = titanic_df.fillna(titanic_df["Embarked"].mode())
```

But I am curious what's with the `second usage` of `inplace=True`.

Please bear with if I'm asking something which is extremely stupid because I' totally new and I may miss small things. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi lU5er.
I found mistyped on your code.
`titanic_df.fillna(titanic_df["Embarked"].mode(), inplace = True)` 
should be `titanic_df["Embarked"].fillna(titanic_df["Embarked"].mode(), inplace = True)` as you did on column ['Age']

Comment: @JessieB That wouldn't work either. `titanic_df["Embarked"].mode()` returns a Series and nan values in that column do not align with that output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [pd.Series.mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) returns a Series.

A variable has a single arithmetic mean and a single median but it may have several modes. If more than one value has the highest frequency, there will be multiple modes.

#### pandas operates on labels.

```
titanic_df.mean()
Out: 
PassengerId    446.000000
Survived         0.383838
Pclass           2.308642
Age             29.699118
SibSp            0.523008
Parch            0.381594
Fare            32.204208
dtype: float64
```

If I were to use `titanic_df.fillna(titanic_df.mean())` it would return a new DataFrame where the column `PassengerId`  is filled with 446.0, column `Survived`  is filled with 0.38 and so on.

However, if I call the mean method on a Series, the returning value is a float:

```
titanic_df['Age'].mean()
Out: 29.69911764705882
```

There is no label associated here. So if I use `titanic_df.fillna(titanic_df['Age'].mean())` all the missing values in all the columns will be filled with 29.699.

#### Why the first attempt was not successful

You tried to fill the entire DataFrame, `titanic_df`  with `titanic_df["Embarked"].mode()`. Let's check the output first:

```
titanic_df["Embarked"].mode()
Out: 
0    S
dtype: object
```

It is a Series with a single element. The index is 0 and the value is S. Now, remember how it would work if we used `titanic_df.mean()` to fill: it would fill each column with the corresponding mean value. Here, we only have one label. So it will only fill values if we have a column named `0`. Try adding `df[0] = np.nan`  and executing your code again. You'll see that the new column is filled with `S`.

#### Why the second attempt was (not) successful

The right hand side of the equation, `titanic_df.fillna(titanic_df["Embarked"].mode())`  returns a new DataFrame. In this new DataFrame, `Embarked` column still has `nan`'s:

```
titanic_df.fillna(titanic_df["Embarked"].mode())['Embarked'].isnull().sum()
Out: 2
```

However you didn't assign it back to the entire DataFrame. You assigned this DataFrame to a Series - `titanic_df['Embarked']`. It didn't actually fill the missing values in the `Embarked`  column, it just used the index values of the DataFrame. If you actually check the new column, you'll see numbers 1, 2, ... instead of S, C and Q.

#### What you should do instead

You are trying to fill a single column with a single value. First, disassociate that value from its label:

```
titanic_df['Embarked'].mode()[0]
Out: 'S'
```

Now, it is not important if you use `inplace=True`  or assign the result back. Both

```
titanic_df['Embarked'] = titanic_df['Embarked'].fillna(titanic_df['Embarked'].mode()[0])
```

and

```
titanic_df['Embarked'].fillna(titanic_df['Embarked'].mode()[0], inplace=True)
```

will fill the missing values in the Embarked column with `S`.

Of course this assumes you want to use the first value if there are multiple modes. You may need to improve your algorithm there (for example randomly select from the values if there are multiple modes).

Comment: Thanks once again for helping me out. :)

Comment: Actually I again made a typo. What JessieB pointed out in the comments was actually I did, but copied it wrong while asking in SO. You found out the real thing and did mend it. Hats Off!